What ever happened to (that NASA link about) SpinSat?
My 2016 question What ever happened to SpinSat - did it work? about the 2012 "Special Purpose Inexpensive Satellite" draws heavily from "NASA's mission pages link for SpinSat" which was at the now-defunct URL

https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/Investigation.html?#id=991

A comment on my question links to

https://www.eoportal.org/satellite-missions/spinsat#mission-status

but that doesn't cover the details of the physical release of SpinSat from the crewed area of the ISS through an airlock and then into space.
A Google Image search for the image below returns two results only; my post, and this Kerbal Space Program Formu on electric solid propellants and their still-working URL to the image is

https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/iss042e016003.jpg

Is that original Mission Page with text that covers SpinSat release from the ISS gone forever, even though links to images on that page still work?

As @OrganicMarble notes, Barry "Butch" Wilmore is currently back on the ISS as a member of "The Boeing Castaways" (cue theme song to Gilligan's Island)


Do you happen to know how long it’s been defunct for?

@Starship No I have no idea. We might hypothesize that it was up in 2016 and that's how the Kerbal Forum post author found the link to the photo, but that's just a guess.

There is an existing page in a similar place, https://www.nasa.gov/mission/station/research-explorer/investigation/?#id=991
which I found by being redirected to https://www.nasa.gov/mission/station/research-explorer/ and typing Spinsat.  Might be a victim of minor reorganization?
Archive has an option to see all its crawls of a given page https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/Investigation.html#id=991 though your Jul 2 2016 query seems to predate that.  The current page doesn't seem to match Archive's oldest snapshot (I can't tell what's trying to load there).  I haven't checked your questions thoroughly to tell if it has the content you expect.

Yay! A quick check shows most if not all of the photos in my 2016 question are there, and that much of the text is there as well, thought I think it's been organized in a new way. Thiis is exactly what I needed. Great work! You should now be a candidate for the nonexistent "space detective" badge :-)  I thought I had actually tried syping SpinSat into the search on the redirect page first and failed, but maybe I just thought about doing it.

@uhoh I do accept badges, even nonexistent ones
